# Pronoun use after a comma

Tags: commas, pronouns

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287976/the-rule-for-the-pronoun-use-after-the-comma/) asks about pronoun usage after a comma.

The answer in that thread makes sense. However, is a pronoun required in situations where the comma's purpose is *not* to separate independent clauses? For example, which of these are acceptable?

I obtained two degrees, in history and math, and received the Dean's Award.

I obtained two degrees, in history and math, and I received the Dean's Award.

Comment: The difference in your examples is not a pronoun issue, but a question of whether to repeat the subject at the top of the sentence. Either works.

Comment: Speak it out loud to decide what's grammatical. Writing and punctuation and such don't count.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the example in the other question, your example uses paired commas to surround a parenthetical<sup>1</sup> phrase.

In your first sentence, two predicates are connected with "and", and no comma is required for that reason. Therefore, if we removed the prepositional phrase we'd have:

> I obtained two degrees and received the Dean's Award.

In your second sentence, two independent clauses are connected with "and", so a comma is required.<sup>2</sup> Therefore, if we removed the prepositional phrase we'd have:

> I obtained two degrees, and I received the Dean's Award.

Both are acceptable.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or "removable", or whatever else you'd like to call it. Terminology varies.
<sup>2</sup>I'm using some pretty traditional punctuation standards. There's certainly a diversity of opinions about commas.

Comment: Could you please add that in your new versions, a comma could be used, or omitted, in both sentences (the one with the subject repeated and also the other one)?  Because commas in those sentences would be a personal, style decision?